# Formatting URLs from array as links

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to pull some URLs from an array and write them to the page as `<a>` HTML elements.

As you can see in the jsfiddle below, for some reason the href is being set as [object text] and the URLs are being added as the link text, which means they don't work. How can I make it such that the href is the URL from my array and the link text is either the URL as well, or something like 'click here'?

**Code**

```
    var title = document.createTextNode(titles[i]),
    author = document.createTextNode(authors[i]),
    url = document.createTextNode(urls[i]),
    titleX = document.createElement('h1'),
    authorX = document.createElement('h2'),
    urlX = document.createElement('a');
    urlX.setAttribute('href', url);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r91h9bpx/)

Comment: That JSFiddle is empty.Please provide your code.

Comment: urlX.setAttribute('href', urls[i]); You missed that url is a TextNode object.

Comment: U need to get the content of text node by accessing the textContent property. e.g. urlX.setAttribute('href',  url.textContent);

Comment: How do I change the link text to something else like 'click here'?

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`urlX.setAttribute('href', url.textContent);`

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `url` is being set to [object Text] is that `setAttribute` converts the value to a string. In your code `url` is a textNode, which when converted to a string is serialized as, well, '`[object Text]'`;

```
> String(document.createTextNode('testing'))
"[object Text]"
```

There really isn't any need to create a textNode for the url:

```
var urlX = document.createElement('a');
urlX.setAttribute('href', urls[i]);
urlX.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click here'));
```

Comment: But then I get a link that looks like this:
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click herehttp://www.google.com</a>

Comment: Hmm.. Could you provide a fiddle (jsfiddle.net)?